# Gaps in time-series for LSTM classification model

Tags: time-series, classification, missing-data, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using an Long short-term memory (LSTM) recurrent neural network model to perform classification of accelerometer sensor data. The experiments (for collecting the data) were run a few months apart and there are gaps throughout the data.

I have read about methods for interpolating and imputing, but since this is for classification and not regression/forecasting, I am wondering if I even need to fill in the gaps.

Would it be reasonable to just sample intervals (sequences) from the time intervals I already have, and train the model on these samples? Any advice would be appreciated, as I am worried I am overlooking something.

Comment: It depends on whether or not the gaps represent data that is missing completely at random (MCAR) or not. If not you might be biasing the results. What caused the missing data and what is the question you are trying to ask with the model?

Comment: @André.B first, thanks for your response. The question I am working on with the model is to classify the behavior of an entity given it's acceleration/position data. The gaps are there due to just not collecting data. Additionally, sometimes the measurements have ms resolution, other times they only recorded down to the seconds resolution.

Comment: From a first thought, it seems like it is MCAR.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using LSTM RNN?

Comment: @André.B The aim is to classify the time-series data, i.e. take sequences of movement/acceleration data and predict the behavior for that time interval (sequence).

Comment: I actually think this may work by just randomly sampling sequences from the same classes and training on those. Then the missing data is a non-problem. Does that make sense?